# access to a globalktable or aglobalstore from a different application - kstream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

we have 2 microservices:

1. responsible for consuming message and update a globalKtable with configuration information (key=id, value=myObject)
2. once it is activated with some id as an input it should look into the configuration globalKtable and retrieve data by that id

how is it possible to access that globalktable from app2.
should a REST layer be added to retrieve the info or Stream has some other capabilities?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have to be "REST". It could be **any _RPC_** layer.

Comment: If you wanted to use HTTP/JSON-RPC, then you can look at https://www.azkarrastreams.io/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Globalktable is local to the micro-service,where it will fetch all the data from all the partition and create a global KTable , which actually keeps the data in a ROCKS DB in the microservice local memory.Any update in against the Kafka key in that topic will automatically reflect in GlobalKTable .From the 2nd MS if u need to access the globalKTable then create the same GlobalKTable in the 2nd MS.